# Fastwap with Lambda expression using weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, lambda, weblogic12c

I am trying to run fast-swap on a file that has java 8 features for eg., lambda expression and it gives me the below error. We are using weblogic 12.1.3 which [supports java8](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES193) as per the release document. Fast swap works for any other classes that doesnt use java 8 features. Any solutions to resolve this ?

```
Root cause of ServletException.
com.bea.wls.redef.ClassRedefinitionException
        at com.bea.wls.redef.ClassRedefinitionRuntime.redefineClasses(ClassRedefinitionRuntime.java:175)
        at weblogic.servlet.utils.FastSwapFilter.redefineClasses(FastSwapFilter.java:87)
        at weblogic.servlet.utils.FastSwapFilter.doFilter(FastSwapFilter.java:63)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Weblogic 12.1 is only [certified](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#NOTES254) for Java 7. Weblogic 12.2 is [certified](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES583) for Java 8.

Comment: @Andreas actually [_Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3 is certified on Java SE 8 Update 20 (u20) and will also be supported on later updates of Java SE 8_](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES193).